# How to change backcolor row in Janus Grid with condition

Tags: c#, janus

How can I change the backcolor row GridEx(GridJanus) with a condition in c#

thanks

Comment: This is not clear enough - can you show us some code?? What have you done so far?? What **condition** do you want to base your decision on?? You need to elaborate a bit more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Grd_Detail_FormattingRow(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowLoadEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < Grd_Detail.RowCount; i++)
    {
        string s = Grd_Detail.GetRow(i).Cells["FN"].Value.ToString();
        if (s == "True")
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowType.Record)
            {                 
                Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXFormatStyle rowcol = new GridEXFormatStyle();
                rowcol.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                Grd_Detail.GetRow(i).RowStyle = rowcol;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't link to it directly, but I found this in a post by *Ravi Kota* on the [Janus Systems](http://www.janusys.com/controls/) forums.  I'm not able to test this at present and it is an older post...  Conceptually it looks right though.

```
GridEXFormatCondition fc;

fc = new GridEXFormatCondition(GridName.RootTable.Columns[ColumnName], ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, 0);

fc.FormatStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;

GridName.RootTable.FormatConditions.Add(fc);
```

Answer (score 1):

On LoadingRow event format row:

```
private void MyGridEX_LoadingRow(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowLoadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowType.Record)
        {
            if ((bool)e.Row.Cells[0].Value)
            {
                Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXFormatStyle style = new Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXFormatStyle();
                style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                e.Row.RowStyle = style;
            }
        }
    }
```